# cannot move Directory not empty

Tags: shell-script, command-line, directory

Edited due to people want to know more then me just wanting to know how to deal with two directories with same names in different places and move one into another when mv will not allow it if files are in destanation area ..

they want to know what I am trying to do and why so ...

my script gets all of the directores within a parent dir then one at a time goes through each dir with the mp3 or flac files in it, then checks to see if resampling needs to be done by bitrate checking, then if bitrate greater then set resample bitrate it resamples the file, if not it skips it, next step : renaming all of the files by TAG information, if it does not have TAG information in the file itself I take it off the dir it is in then add that to it by artist dir and album dir or other means nevertheless the TAG information is added to file if needed then I use that META TAG informatio to rename the file.

song - artist.mp3

with this script I keep the files witin the orgial dirs when the script has completed working on all of the files within that artist dir it then needs to be move out of that partent dir so that when this script is ran again it will not go back over all of the files that have just been completed ...

so I have it rename that artist dir to the artist name because some of them have artist / album / discography @320MP3 crap all written within the Directory name -- so i clean it up bu just renaming it the artist off the META TAG Artsit info, then move it to another parent dir to keep all of the ones completed within that dir sys.

because I have many of same artist different albums dir names, as well as duplecate files within different dirs all in a parent dir. all the same artist with different named dirs -- Example -

1
Alice Cooper mad man/album name/Old-files

when complete it will be

Alice Cooper/album name/New-files

2
Alice Cooper whatever else is here/album/CD1/Old-iles

Alice Cooper whatever else is here/album/CD2/Old-files

when done it will be

Alice Cooper/album/CD1/New-iles

Alice Cooper/album/CD2/New-files

the steps :

loop one is to get dir name to work on

loop two is to go through every file within that dir structor and resmaple, reTag if needed, rename files , when all files are completed rename the dir to the artist name, then move it out of that parent dir into a different Parent dir to get it out of the way -

next dir within that parent dir 
repeat steps

problem
when loop comes across a match for Album name that has already been renamed and move to the different parent dir it raises that error.

```
mv -f /from/here/sameNameDir    /to/here/ - that has the same name dir in it already
```

If Dir not moved then the script will just cycle through all of the files that are already completed waisting time as I have over 40,000 files it takes time to do this so I just move the complete dir out of there so on a second run of the script the next day it can start new

My Script it works but has a few bugs in it so it is still in testing mode so it has a lot of echo's in it : as well as I reuse code I 've written so you may see movie comments in there as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

# started writting this on 11-24-2015


typeset -i FilesCountInSecondLoop    FilesInDirCount  filesLeftToDo   DirCountDn
let        FilesCountInSecondLoop=0  FilesInDirCount=0 filesLeftToDo=0 DirCountDn=0

typeset -i cycleThroughFilesCount    
let        cycleThroughFilesCount=0  

working_dir="/media/data/test-run"

move_to="/media/data/move_to_test"


# where you keep this script to run it in a terminal
# it is written so that you do not have to put it in the 
# working directory or directories to eliminate having to put
# a separate script in every folder to run it
##############################################

 script_dir="$HOME/working"


# max rate you want your orgianl files to be check for to be 
# resampled at

LameCheckRate=192

# bitrate you want your FLAC files coverted to mp3 in
# you can convert your FLAC to a higher rate then the
# resmapled mp3 if you like 
##################################

flac_convert_brate=192

# this is the FLAC settings it runs at
# flac -cd "$FILENAME" | lame -b "${flac_convert_brate}" - "$newFile" 


# LAME settings VBR low and High end

LameLowEnd=128 
LameHighEnd=192

# this is the LAME settings it runs at
##lame -V2 -b"${LameLowEnd}" -B"${LameHighEnd}" -F --vbr-new -m j -q2

#####################
## DO NOT CHANGE ####
runTime=1 ###########        
convertN=$1 #########
#####################
# gets amount of files wanted to resample on run
# from command line args
function rst(){

if [[ convertN -lt runTime ]]; then
  echo " you forgot to enter an amount to resample"
  ConvertNum=0
  exit 1
  else
  ConvertNum=$((convertN))
  return $ConvertNum #pass the var to space land

fi

}

rst

# var to keep amount of dirs desired to be done per run of script
# amount of files in the dir may not allow to get done in one day 
 amount_of_dir_to_work_on=$ConvertNum

echo ""$working_dir" START - creating list of files"

# get all of the names of the base dir to change name  a var containing ampunt of basenamedir in last place here 
#   amount_of_dir_to_work_on this is gotten off of the command line

    find "$working_dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | while [ $DirCountDn  -lt $amount_of_dir_to_work_on ] ; 
        do read DIRNAME;
                    echo "$DIRNAME"



                #get list of all files in dir and sub dir's of current Dir to work off of

                    MAXMP3="$(find "$DIRNAME" -type f -name "*.mp3" | wc -l)"
                    MAXFLAC="$(find "$DIRNAME" -type f -name "*.flac" | wc -l)"

                    echo;echo;echo
                    echo "amount of mp3 "$MAXMP3" in "$DIRNAME""


                    FilesCountInSecondLoop=$(($MAXMP3 + $MAXFLAC))
                    filesLeftToDo="$FilesCountInSecondLoop" 



                    echo "Just starting off"
                    echo "MAXMP3 is               : "$MAXMP3""
                    echo "MAXFLAC is              : "$MAXFLAC""
                    echo "FilesCountInSecondLoop  : "$FilesCountInSecondLoop""
                    echo "Files left to do        : "$filesLeftToDo""
                    echo "cycleThroughFilesCount  : "$cycleThroughFilesCount""


                                                                      # MAXMP3 starts with a number 
                                                                       #  if not equle to 
                                                                       # cycleThroughFilesCount starts with zero         
    find "$DIRNAME" -type f -name "*.*" | while [ $FilesCountInSecondLoop -ne $cycleThroughFilesCount ] ;
        do read FILENAME;



                    #Directory to put the files back into it after resampling is completed  

                    r=$FILENAME

                    c=$FILENAME
                    xpath=${c%/*} 
                    xbase=${c##*/}
                    xfext=${xbase##*.}
                    xpref=${xbase%.*}
                    path=${xpath}
                    pref=${xpref}
                    ext=${xfext}


                    #checks to see if varitable is empty meaning no files to that extention to 
                    #resample are left to do --
                    if [ -z "$ext" ]; then 
                        echo "all Done - dar eay."
                        exit 1
                    fi

        #############################
        ############################
        ###
        ### GET RID OF EVERYTHING THAT IS NOT A MP3 OR FLAC FILE
        ###
        ##############################################################


        #Checks each movie file to see if it is just a not needed sample of the move to regain file space by deleting it

                    for file in "${path}" ; do 
                    #   echo "in for loop ext1 is -> "$ext"" 

                        if [[ "$ext" != 'flac' && "$ext" != 'mp3' && "ext" != 'jpg' ]]; then

                        #   echo "in loop if statment ext is -> "$ext""
                        #  echo "Removing "$FILENAME""

                        removeme="$FILENAME"
                        rm -v "$removeme"

                        # set a different ext type so that it will not go into following if statement due to it is still a movie extention
                        # causes it to skip over and go to next file
                        ## ext1="foobar"

                        let InIfLoop++
                    #   echo "in IF Loop ="${InIfLoop}""
                        fi
                            let inLoop++
                            #echo "inside of loop ="${inLoop}"" 
                    done

                        let leftLoop++
                        #echo "left loop count = "$leftLoop""


        ####################
        ###
        ### START ON MP3 or FLAC FILE
        ###
        ###############################################


        #echo "Extention off before into first if statment "${ext}""
        # echo

                    if [[ "${ext}" == 'mp3' || "${ext}" == 'flac' ]] ; then 

                        echo;echo
                        echo $FILENAME " Looking to resample this FILE now!"
                        echo;echo

        #############################################################
        #get the metadata tags off the mp3's using exiftool-perl
        #################

                ALBUM1="`exiftool  -Album  "$FILENAME" -p '$Album'`"
                ARTIST1="`exiftool -Artist "$FILENAME" -p '$Artist'`"
                SongName="`exiftool  -Title  "$FILENAME" -p '$Title'`"
                TRACK1=""
                TRACK2=""
                TRACK1="`exiftool "-Track Number" "$FILENAME" -p '$TrackNumber'`"
                TRACK2="`exiftool  -Track  "$FILENAME" -p '$Track'`"

                #GENRE1="`exiftool  -Genre "$FILENAME" -p '$Genre'`"
            #   echo "track 1  -> "$TRACK1""
            #   echo "track 2  -> "$TRACK2""
                #gets the number off the left side of file name if any then
                # hopefully fixs it to tag track number in file

                number=${pref//[^0-9 ]/}
                number=${number%% *}
                number=${number%/*}
        #removes leading white space on both ends of string
                number="$(echo -e "${number}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"

            #   echo "NUMBER IS now = "$number""

                if [ -z "${TRACK1}" ] && [ -z "${TRACK2}" ] ; then  
                    id3v2 -T "$number" "${FILENAME}"
                    echo "aftering adding track"
                    TRACK1="`exiftool "-Track Number" "$FILENAME" -p '$TrackNumber'`"
                    TRACK2="`exiftool  -Track  "$FILENAME" -p '$Track'`"
                    echo "this is track1 "$TRACK1""
                    echo "This is TRACK2 "$TRACK2""
                    echo

                fi



    #replaces all the crap and the spaces 
    #between the names with an underscore
    #"${x// /_}" meaning "${varName//search pattern/replace with}"


     echo "GETTING OFF TAGS"
    #echo
     echo "ARTIST1 going in is "$ARTIST1""
            newArt="${ARTIST1// / }"
            newArt="${newArt#/*}"
            newArt=${newArt//[^A-Za-z&0-9"'" ]/ }
            newArt="$(echo -e "${newArt}" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g")"
    #ensure only one space between each word
            newArt="$(echo -e "${newArt}" | sed -e 's/\s+/ /g')"
    #removes leading white space on both ends of string
            newArt="$(echo -e "${newArt}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
     echo "newArt comming out is -> "$newArt""


            newTit="${SongName// / }"
            newTit=${newTit//[^A-Za-z&0-9"'" ]/ }
    #Capitalizes each word
            newTit="$(echo -e "${newTit}" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g")"
    #ensure only one space between each word
            newTit="$(echo -e "${newTit}" | sed -e 's/\s+/ /g')"
    #removes leading white space on both ends of string
            newTit="$(echo -e "${newTit}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
    #echo "NEW TITLE comming out is"
     echo "$newTit"


    #echo "ALBUM1 going in is -> "$ALBUM1""
            newAlb="${ALBUM1%/*}" 
            newAlb=${newAlb//[^A-Za-z&0-9"'" ]/ }
    #Capitalizes each word
            newAlb="$(echo -e "${newAlb}" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g")"
    #ensure only one space between each word
            newAlb="$(echo -e "${newAlb}" | sed -e 's/\s+/ /g')"
    #removes leading white space on both ends of string
            newAlb="$(echo -e "${newAlb}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
     echo "newAlb commming out is -> "${newAlb}""
    #echo "DONE GETTING OFF TAGS"
    #echo
    #strip the orginal file name off the path from FILENAME
        c=$FILENAME
        xpath=${c%/*} 
        xbase=${c##*/}
        xfext=${xbase##*.}
        xpref=${xbase%.*}
        path=${xpath}
        pref=${xpref}
        ext=${xfext}

    ####################################

        c=$FILENAME

    ##############################
    # if MP3 has no needed tag information then 
    # strips names off of directory folders then uses them
    # as artist/band -- and album names in tags before renaming mp3 file
    ##########################
    # echo "GETTING OFF OF DIRECTORIES"

    # echo "STARTING TO EXTRACT DIRECTORIES NAMES"
        file=${c##*/}
        album1=${c#*"${c%/*/"$file"}"/}
        Artist=${album1%/*}
        Artist1=${c#*"${c%/*/"$album1"}"/}
        album=${album1%%/*}
        Artist2=${Artist1%%/*}
    #    echo "right here YO"
        dir=${FILENAME#*/*/*/*/} 
        dir=${dir//\/*}
        echo "$dir"
    #rename directory
        NewDirectoryName="$dir" 
    #   echo "$NewDirectoryName"
        NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName%%'('*}
        NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName%%'320cbr'*}
        NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName%'[Bubanee]'*}
        NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName%'MP3'*}
        NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName%'2CD'*}
        NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName%'Discography'*}
        NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName%'discography'*}
        NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName//[^A-Za-z ]/ }
    #Capitalizes each word
        NewDirectoryName="$(echo -e "${NewDirectoryName}" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g")"
    #ensure only one space between each word
        NewDirectoryName="$(echo -e "${NewDirectoryName}" | sed -e 's/\s+/ /g')"
    #removes leading white space on both ends of string
        NewDirectoryName="$(echo -e "${NewDirectoryName}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
    #echo "newAlb after striaghtening it up -> "${newAlb}""
    #   echo "NewDirectoryName is --- -> "$NewDirectoryName""
    #   echo

        e=$FILENAME
        xpath=${e%/*} 
        xbase=${e##*/}
        xfext=${xbase##*.}
        xpref=${xbase%.*}
        path1=${xpath}
        pref1=${xpref}
        ext1=${xfext}

    # echo "song off directory is -> "$pref1""
        songTitle="${pref1}"
        songTitle=${songTitle//[^A-Za-z&0-9"'" ]/ }
    #Capitalizes each word
        songTitle="$(echo -e "${songTitle}" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g")"
    #ensure only one space between each word
        songTitle="$(echo -e "${songTitle}" | sed -e 's/\s+/ /g')"
    #removes leading white space on both ends of string
        songTitle="$(echo -e "${songTitle}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
    #   echo "newAlb after striaghtening it up -> "${newAlb}""
    #   echo "new songTitle is -> "$songTitle""

    #  echo "DONE GETTING OFF OF DIRECTORIES"
    #echo;echo;
        if [ -z "$ALBUM1" ] ; then
            id3v2 -A "$newAlb1" "${FILENAME}"
            echo "tagging Album tag to file is -> "$newAlb1" "
            echo
        fi

        if [ -z "$ARTIST1" ] ; then
            id3v2 -a "$Artist" "${FILENAME}"
            echo "tagging Artist tag to file is -> "$Artist" "
            newArt=$Artist
            echo
        fi

        if [ -z "$SongName" ] ; then
            id3v2 -t "$songTitle" "${FILENAME}"
            echo "tagging Title tag to file is -> "$songTitle" "
            newTit=$songTitle 
            echo
        fi


    # MAKING NEW FILE NAME 
    ###########################


        ALBUM1="`exiftool  -Album  "$FILENAME" -p '$Album'`"

    #   echo "JFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDF"


        function GetArt () {
            if [[ ! -n "$ARTIST" ]]; then
                Art=$((ARTIST))
                #echo " got someting "

                return $Art #pass the var to space land
            fi
        }
            GetArt
          echo "this is the newAt justbefore making newFIle "$newArt""
        newFile=""${newTit}" - "${newArt}".mp3"

    # get the size of the Orginal File and keep for later use
        FileSize1="`exiftool '-File Size'  "$FILENAME" -p '$FileSize'`"


    #if song was already resampled it skips it then goes onto next one
        echo "******************************************************************"
    # echo "this is old file name about to be checked if matches new FileName"
    # echo "right here -> "$pref" new File name -> "${newFile%.*}""
    # echo
    ## REMOVE the Extention off of NewFile to check string
    #   if [[ "$pref" != "${newFile%.*}" ]] ; then

         if [[ "$pref" == "${newFile%.*}" ]] ; then
       echo;echo
                echo "This file -> :: "${newFile%.*}" " :: has already been done, skipping""

                let cycleThroughFilesCount++
                let filesLeftToDo--
                echo "amount of mp3   : "$MAXMP3" in "$DIRNAME""
                echo "MP 3 left to do : "$filesLeftToDo""
                echo "MP3 done        : "$cycleThroughFilesCount"" 
                echo;echo
         else

    #######################################
    #
    # CHECK BITRATE of MP3 = 192 - 160 vbr
    # CHOP OFF ENDING .00000
    # STORE IN VAR for checking value
    #########################################



        if [[ "${ext1}" == 'mp3' ]] ; then
    #rateme="$(mp3info -r a -p "%r\n" "${FILENAME}")"
    #rateis="${rateme%.*}" # strip off period and everything to the right of it
            echo
            rateis="$(mp3info -r m -p "%r\n" "${FILENAME}")"
            echo "Bitrate for "$pref1"."$ext1" is $rateis"
            echo    
            echo "LameCheckRate is "$LameCheckRate""
            echo
            echo "flac_convert_brate is "$flac_convert_brate""
            echo;echo
        fi
            echo;echo
        putback=${r%/*}
        echo "THIS IS PUT BACK DIR = "$putback""
echo;echo;  echo;echo;  echo;echo;  echo;echo;  echo;echo
    ##############################################################
    # Resampling FLAC with LAME 99.9.5  
    ###
    ##

        if [[ "${ext}" == 'flac' ]] ; then
            echo "got Dflack file  "${pref}"."${ext}""
            echo "converting to "${flac_convert_brate}" /kbps mp3"
            echo

            flac -cd "$FILENAME" | lame -h -b "${flac_convert_brate}" - "$newFile" 

            echo;echo;
    # get new bitrate and spit it out to the terminal
            rateis="$(mp3info -r m -p "%r\n" "$script_dir"/"${newFile}")"
            echo "Bitrate of .. $newFile   .. is .. $rateis .."
            echo;echo

            eyeD3 -A "$newAlb" "${script_dir}"/"${newFile}"
            echo "added "$newAlb" tag to file"

            eyeD3 -a "$newArt" "${script_dir}"/"${newFile}"
            echo "added "$newArt" tag to file"

            eyeD3 -t "$songTitle" "${script_dir}"/"${newFile}"
            echo "added "$songTitle" tag to file" 


        if [[ ! -n "${TRACK1}" ]] ; then        
            eyeD3 -n "$TRACK2" "${script_dir}"/"${newFile}"
            echo "added T2 - "$TRACK2" tag to file" 

        else 
            eyeD3 -n "$TRACK1" "${script_dir}"/"${newFile}"
            echo "added T1 - "$TRACK1" tag to file" 

        fi

            eyeD3 -G "$GENRE1"  "${script_dir}"/"${newFile}"
            echo "added "$GENRE1" tag to file" 
            echo;echo
            echo "after insert info "
            echo;echo "after reasiging FLAC resmapling" echo
            echo
        fi

    ##############################################################
    # Resampling MP3  with LAME 99.9.5  
    ###
    #flack file resampled into a MP3 falls through here and gets moved too
    # if MP3 is out of limits then re-sample it if not then send it through
        if [[ "${ext}" == 'mp3' ]] ; then
    # start bitrate       128        start bitrate       160
            if [[ "${rateis}" -gt "${LameCheckRate}" ]] ; then


        lame -V2 -b"${LameLowEnd}" -B"${LameHighEnd}" -F --vbr-new -m j -q2 "$FILENAME" "$newFile"
            echo
            echo "MOVING FILES NOW!"
            echo
            echo "$newFile"
            echo
    ## Resampled file is newFile located in script dir
            rm -v "${FILENAME}"
            echo;echo
            mv -v "${script_dir}"/"${newFile}" "${putback}"
            echo
            fileplace="${putback}"/"${newFile}"
            id3v2 -A "$newAlb" "${fileplace}"
            id3v2 -a "$newArt" "${fileplace}"
            id3v2 -t "$newTit" "${fileplace}"
            echo;echo "after move"
            exiftool "${putback}"/"${newFile}"

            let filesLeftToDo--
            let cycleThroughFilesCount++
            echo;echo "mp3's done "$cycleThroughFilesCount""
            else
    # if MP3 is within limits then skip resmapling then just make 
    # a copy to move it 
    # to new directory/folder
    ## WORKING SCRIPT DIRECTORY !
            echo;echo "is not needing resampling"
            echo "$pref1"."$ext"
            echo;echo "new file name is -> "${newFile}""
            echo

    #if old file name changed the change it
            compareme="${putback}"/"${newFile}"
            if [[ "${FILENAME}" != "${compareme}" ]] ; then

            mv -v "${FILENAME}" "${putback}"/"${newFile}"
            echo;echo "after not needing resample"
            echo
            exiftool "${putback}"/"${newFile}"

            let filesLeftToDo--
            let cycleThroughFilesCount++
            echo;echo "mp3 done "$cycleThroughFilesCount""

            fi
            echo;echo


            eyeD3 -A "$newAlb" "${putback}"/"${newFile}"
            echo "Non resampled stats"
    #exiftool "${script_dir}"/"${newFile}"

        fi

fi # end first if


            echo "Total MP3's Files are      : "$MAXMP3""
            echo "Files done so far is       : "$cycleThroughFilesCount""
            echo "MP3's left to do are       : "$filesLeftToDo""

# echo "After mp3 resampling file ->"
# exiftool "${script_dir}"/"${newFile}"

# I use EXIFTOOL because it works on FLAC files too for
# extracting the information
    echo;echo;





# get the size of the finished file to show differece in size of file
    echo "putback is --------  "$putback""
    checkme=""${putback}"/"${newFile}"" 
    FileSize2="`exiftool '-File Size' "$checkme" -p '$FileSize'`"


    fi


fi # end checking string for done file 


###########################################
## DO THE MATH ON MEGABYTES SAVED #########
###########################################

# if it cathces a KB file then it throws off the math. adding
# this keeps MB rounded up to the nearest whole one MB. 
    echo
    Hold1=$FileSize1
    Hold2=$FileSize2

    k1="${Hold1#* }"
    echo ""$k1" -- k1"

    if [[ "$k1" == 'kB' ]] ; then
        MB1=1
    else
        MB1="${FileSize1% *}"
    fi

    k2="${Hold2#* }"
    echo ""$k2" -- k2"

    if [[ "$k2" == 'kB' ]] ; then
        MB2=1
    else
        MB2="${FileSize2% *}"
    fi


# if it cannot stat file -- file unfound - bad file - then put a 
# zero in place of nothing to keep the total 
    if [[ "$FileSize1" == "" ]] ; then
        MB1=0
    fi

    if [[ "$FileSize2" == "" ]] ; then
        MB2=0
    fi

        echo "  "$MB1"  MB1 - start size"
        echo "- "$MB2"  MB2 - ending size"

# doing math on MB's
        totalSaveOnFile=`echo $MB1 - $MB2 | bc`
    echo "----------"
    echo "  "$totalSaveOnFile" MB - regained space" 
    echo "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
    echo
    #maxSaved=$(( totalSaveOnFile + maxSaved ))


    maxSaved=`echo $totalSaveOnFile + $maxSaved | bc`
    echo
    echo "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
    echo;echo;echo
                            echo "***************************************"
                            echo;echo;echo





                            echo "AT IF STATMENTS"

                            echo "FILENAME is "$FILENAME""
                            NEWFILENAME=${FILENAME%/*}
                            #DIRNAME=${DIRNAME#*/*/*/*/} 
                            #DIRNAME=${DIRNAME//\/*}
                            echo "DIRNAME is "$DIRNAME""


                            echo "before if to do it"
                            echo "FilesCountInSecondLoop : "$FilesCountInSecondLoop""
                            echo "MAXMP3                 : "$MAXMP3""

                            if [[ "$FilesCountInSecondLoop" == "$cycleThroughFilesCount" ]] ; then

                                    echo " in if fileCount check"
                                    echo " NEWFILENAME is  "${NEWFILENAME}""
                                    echo "new file is "${newFile}""
                                    ARTIST1="`exiftool -Artist "${NEWFILENAME}"/"${newFile}" -p '$Artist'`"
                                    NewDirName="$ARTIST1"
                                    echo "new dir name is "$NewDirName""
                                    echo "this is MP3Count - "$MP3Count""
                                    #var names for dir nd paths and string compair
                                    OldDirName="$DIRNAME"
                                    echo;echo "OldDirName "$OldDirName""
                                    stringOldDir=${DIRNAME#*/*/*/*/}                                
                                    stringOldDir=${stringOldDir//\/*}
                                    echo;echo "stringOldDir "$stringOldDir""
                                    stringNewDir="$NewDirName"
                                    echo;echo "stringNewDir "$stringNewDir""
                                    oldDirPathNewName=""$working_dir"/"$NewDirName""
                                    echo;echo "oldDirPathNewName "$oldDirPathNewName""

                                 # if orginal dir name does not equals artist Tag name
                                 # change the dir to Artist Tag name then move it

                                 if [[ "$stringOldDir" != "$stringNewDir" ]] ; then  
                                    echo "not = "$stringOldDir" to "$stringNewDir""
                                            #change name of dir to artist/band name
                                                echo "mv OldDirName "$OldDirName" to "$oldDirPathNewName""
                                                echo "Working dir "$working_dir""

                                                #change old dir name to new dir name
                                                mv -v "$OldDirName" "$oldDirPathNewName"

                                                #then check to be sure root dir to move it to is there
                                                if [[ ! -d "$move_to" ]] ; then
                                                        echo "inside if more to dir is there"
                                                        mkdir -v "$move_to" 
                                                        #then move the new dir name to a different
                                                        # place for safe keeping
                                                        echo;echo "just befor move "
                                                        echo "oldDirPathNewName "$oldDirPathNewName" move to "$move_to""
                                                        mv -vf "$oldDirPathNewName" "$move_to" 
                                                else
                                                    echo "ELSE oldDirPathNewName "$oldDirPathNewName" move to "$move_to""
                                                    #if dir already created then just move the new dir there
                                                            mv -vf "$oldDirPathNewName" "$move_to"
                                                fi
                                fi

                        #if old dir name matches Artist Tag then insure more to dir is there then move it there

                                if [[ "$stringOldDir" == "$stringNewDir" ]] ; then  
                                  echo "Match strings "$stringOldDir" and "$stringNewDir""
                                    if [[ ! -d "move_to" ]] ; then
                                        mkdir -v "$move_to"
                                        mv -vf "$OldDirName" "$move_to" 
                                    else
                                        mv -fv "$OldDirName" "$move_to" 
                                    fi

                                fi
                        fi



    done
    let DirCountDn++
                echo "Dir Count Dn "$DirCountDn"" 
                echo "******************************************" 
                echo;echo;echo

done #FOR DIR Names
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why are you moving directories and not files? If the directory already exists, why would you move it instead of just moving the files it contains? The error you show only occurs when a directory of that name already exists.

Comment: I have a script that resamples all music files in dir's mp3 and flac then keeps the resampled files in orginal dir - then deletes the old file -- when it gets doen cycling through the entire dir and sub dirs resmapling all music files I need to get rid of that dir - move it out of the root dir with all of the rest of the OTHER dir that still have files that need to be resmapled. so when I run this script again it will not redo or try to redo what was already done.

Comment: what??  "I need to get rid of _that_ dir" what dir?? ... "move it out of the root dir" that's not what you're trying above... "with all of the rest of the OTHER dir that still have files that need to be resampled" ... in the same directory tree? You'rve no resampled them, so why are you trying to move them? 

Look: Make a tree marked "original" and a different tree marked "resampled". At the start, all albums are in Original. Now, after _each_ file you resample, move it to the "resampled" tree (or better yet, save it directly to that tree).

Comment: it runs every file within that one dir first before touching it to rename it then moves to the next dir and does the same   I  am trying to now check the other parent dir for like name if true then move the contents into that same name dir then remove old dir then move on to a different dir to resample all of them files in it then do the same --

Comment: I have another script that resamlpes and make a different tree for all of the finished files but it gets me too many copys of same file due to orgianl dir has different name same songs in it, trying to clean it up and resamle and rid copies all at the same time :) its a work in progress ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had it check to see if parent dir was already created in the different desanation base folder then if true just copy into it then delete the old dir else move the whole thing

```
                            ## check to see if other parent dir  is there if not then make it so
                            if [[ ! -d "$move_to" ]] ; then
                                mkdir -v "$move_to"
                            fi

                        # if old dir does not match new dir name then change it

                                 if [[ "$stringOldDir" != "$stringNewDir" ]] ; then  
                                    echo "not = "$stringOldDir" to "$stringNewDir""


                                            #change name of dir to artist/band name
                                                echo "mv OldDirName "$OldDirName" to "$oldDirPathNewName""


                                                #change old dir name to new dir name
                                                mv -v "$OldDirName" "$oldDirPathNewName"
                                fi


                        #check if other parent dir and artist are there if not handle it

                                if [[ ! -d "$move_to"/"$stringNewDir" ]] ; then

                                            echo "inside ck if move to parent / artist to dir is there"
                                            echo
                                            echo ""$move_to"/"$stringNewDir" is not there moving "$stringNewDir""
                                            echo                                    
                                            #then move the new dir name to a different
                                            # place for safe keeping
                                            echo
                                            echo;echo "just befor move "
                                            echo
                                            echo "oldDirPathNewName "$oldDirPathNewName" move to "$move_to""
                                            echo            
                                            mv -vf "$oldDirPathNewName" "$move_to"/"$stringNewDir" 
                                            echo            

                                else
                                            echo ""$move_to"/"$stringNewDir" is there moving within it into"
                                            echo
                                            echo "$move_to"/"$stringNewDir"
                                            echo
                                            moveinsideof="$oldDirPathNewName"
                                            echo
                                            cp -Rv "${moveinsideof}"/* "$move_to"/"$stringNewDir" 
                                            echo
                                            rm -rv "$oldDirPathNewName"
                                fi

            fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in two steps, first moving the files and then deleting the now empty parent directory:

```
mkdir -p to/there
mv from/here/* to/there
rmdir from/here
```

In your concrete case, the fragment

```
if [[ "$stringOldDir" == "$stringNewDir" ]] ; then  
   echo "Match strings "$stringOldDir" and "$stringNewDir""
   if [[ ! -d "move_to" ]] ; then
     mkdir -v "$move_to"
     mv -vf "$OldDirName" "$move_to" 
   else
     mv -fv "$OldDirName" "$move_to" 
   fi
 fi
```

can be replaced by something like this:

```
mkdir -p "$move_to/$OldDirName"
mv "$OldDirName"/* "$move_to/$OldDirName"
rmdir "$move_to/$OldDirName"
```

Comment: its in a script that auto runs and hits random dir that throw that error -- need to know ow to catch that error and then handle it trying that code -- or a work around to have the sctipt just jump into the moved to dir that holds all of the modified files then rename the directoies, but that too may pose an error if another dir of the same name is already there too ---

Comment: @uxserx-bw I do not quite get what you are aiming at and why my suggestion does not work for you. To execute some special code in case the move failed, try `movecommand || specialcommand`. Is that what you meant? If not, could you update your question such that it explains what exactly the intended behavior of your script is?

Comment: every time I try to give more information people just get more confused about what I am doing with my sctiprt because it does quite a few operations. I'm going to try and make it as clear as possiable what my script is doing then get to the part or parts  I am having troble with -- please read it again in a few minutes as of this posting to you

Comment: @uxserx-bw It seems to me that moving the files instead of the directory as suggested above should work in both cases (note that I also added a `mkdir`, in case the new directory does not exist yet). So there is no real need to detect and handling any error. Or I'm still not quite getting the problem.

Comment: I am resampling mp3/flac to mp3 then orginizing them now I am keepig them in same dir del the old file after renaming it -- then when that directory is fully completed with all of the mp3/flac files rename the parent dir to the artist name off META TAG info for duplicate dir with different parent names of same artist then moveing that whole completed dir with it's subdir's into a different parent tree Music/newDIr Artist name goes here/SubDIr's/all of the files now get rid of matching dir and all of its contents in OLD Parent DIr. Y? I have a lot of duplicate files with Different DIr names

Comment: @uxserx-bw I added some more explanation. It that does not address your problem, please describe concisely in which way that solution behaves differently from what you expect.

Comment: no more problems I even added my own answer in here but this place will not let me pick my own "right" anwer to close it out - or mark solved -- stupid as that is - it is ...go and take a peek at it if you like --

Answer (score 2):

The mv command can do a variety of things depending on the types of its arguments, and there are some cases where it might not be able to do exactly what you want. It doesn't really handle merging two nonempty directories.

The [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html) says this:

> If the destination path exists, mv shall attempt to remove it. If this fails for any reason, mv shall write a diagnostic message to standard error, do nothing more with the current source_file, and go on to any remaining source_files.

And that's what you're running into here. `mv dbyls /m/d/t/dbyls`, where both arguments are directories, will try to remove `/m/d/t/dbyls`. If the directory is not empty, it will fail.

The typical workaround is to do `mv dblys/*  /m/d/t/dbyls`, followed by `rmdir dblys`. Note that `*` might not match files that begin with `.`, depending on your shell environment.

Comment: is there a way to catch that error so the script can know when to do that code you suggested --

Comment: @uxserx-bw Something like `if test -d "$destdir" && ! rmdir -- "$destdir"; then echo "Directory $destdir is nonempty - try plan B"; fi`. `rmdir` will not remove a directory if there's anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1 - Use `rsync + rm`

Though its man page doesn't document it, `mv` will refuse to rename a directory to another directory if the target directory contains files. This is a good thing in your case because you turn out to want to *merge* the content of the source into the target, which `mv` will not do.

Use `rsync -a backup/ backupArchives/` instead. After that `rm -rf backup/*`.

Instead of using `rsync`, you also can do the classical

```
(cd backup && tar c .) | (cd backupArchives && tar xf -)
```

which earns you more geek points.

### Option 2 - Use `cp + rm`

Quick and dirty, if you know what you are doing:

`cp -r ./backup/* ./backupArchives && rm -R ./backup/*`

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/269775/mv-directory-not-empty/269818#269818